# Authentication to awx /websocket

Tags: ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I have trouble authenticating to awx websocket from my javascript app.

The documentation says: "You can connect to the AWX channels implementation using any standard websocket library by pointing it to /websocket. You must provide a valid Auth Token in the request URL."

I have token that I use for API authorization ("Authorization": "Bearer ") and it works like charm. But I cannot figure the proper way to use it with websocket URL. I have tried "ws://localhost:30380/websocket/?access_token=" but it did not work. It does not work with ?token= either.
Can you help me please?